# AngularJS Select box - ngClick not firing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select box which contains the  `ng-model` directive. I want to fire an event when the user clicks on the select box (which will trigger before selecting an option).

```
<select id="count" name="count" class="form-control" ng-click="vm.clickCountSelector();" ng-model="vm.count" 
 ng-options="c.name for c in vm.getEligibleCountList()" required validation-messages></select>
```

But `vm.clickCountSelector()` doesn't fire when it should. How can I achieve this? Is there any way to trigger this event?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you debug the code? what is the error it is showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but I would suggest to bind to ng-change for a select element. The ng-click will fire after you select an option.

If you really want to get a event you can use ng-mousedown.

```js
var ngApp = angular.module('ngAppl',[]);

function aControlla($scope){
    $scope.count = function(){
       alert("It works!");
    }
    
    $scope.values = [
        {Name: "Entry 1"},
        {Name: "Entry 2"},
        {Name: "Entry 3"},
        {Name: "Entry 4"}
    ];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngAppl">
    <div ng-controller="aControlla">
        
        <select ng-mousedown="count(val)" ng-model="val">
          <option ng-repeat="val in values" value ={{val.Name}}>
            {{val.Name}}
          </option>
        </select>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-change instead of ng-click.

Comment: But I want to know whether user clicks ON the select box.

Comment: Then you should keep examining why vm.clickCountSelector() is not firing. Like you said it has only alert now, but maybe you didn't even notice that function is triggered because you prevented alerts on browser. My advice for you is to always debug your code with console.log("Something") and then just look at your console to see if something happened.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to add a $event in the call of your function ?

```
vm.clickCountSelector($event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('NgListController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Item1'
  }, {
    name: 'Item2'
  }];


  $scope.clickCountSelector = function() {

    alert('select clicked');
  }



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <fieldset ng-controller="NgListController">
    <select id="count" name="count" class="form-control" ng-click="clickCountSelector();" ng-model="vm.count" ng-options="c.name for c in items" required validation-messages></select>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

on select tag you can do ng-change instead ng-click. but if you want to capture ng-click on it, keep your select tag inside  p or div tag and use ng-click on those tags. you may not be able to differentiate click if you have multiple tags inside a p or div tag.